# Create ordering in a MySQL table without using a number (because then it's hard to put something in between)

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a long list of items (say, a few million items) in a mysql table, let's call it mytable and it has the field mytable.itemid.

The items are given an order, and can be re=ordered by the user by drag and drop. If I add a field called mytable.order and just put numbers in them, it creates problems: what if I want to move an item between 2 other items? Then all the order fields have to be updated? That seems like a nightmare.

Is there a (scalable) way to add order to a table that is different from just giving every item a number, order by that, and do loads of SQL queries everytime the order is changed?

Comment: You could use floating point values, or you could space out the numbers to begin with, for instance use 1000, 2000, 3000, etc. and then halve each interval when you need to move rows in between them. Eventually you would have to adjust some numbers, but it would happen with larger intervals than for every move. Also, if you move one item up 10 rows when using sequential numbers, you would only have to adjust 11 rows. First adjust the 10 rows above the one you're moving, up by one, and then set the moving rows sort order to the new value.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a trigger or stored procedure to resequence the order values appropriately, or drop all the associated records and insert new ones in the new order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fractions (two integers, i.e. a/b). Always there is at least one rational between two other.

Comment: Using 2 separate numbers doesn't give me an easy way to sort in MySQL though.